# ASP Make invisible element visible

Tags: html, asp.net, checkbox, webforms, visible

On my web page is a large table and a checkbox. Initially, the table is not shown. When the checkbox is checked, the javascript calls `tablename.SetVisible(cb.GetChecked())`. This fails because the invisible table is simply not on the page and cannot be made visible. The debugger says:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'tablename' is undefined

If I set the table to be visible, then run the web page, the checkbox works nicely and is able to make the table invisible and visible again.

But the table is really big and generally annoyable, so how do I get the checkbox to work with the table initially invisible?

In fact, this is with DevExpress controls, but I feel that this is not a DevExpress issue.

Server side source is just:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    gridResults.DataSource = ds.Tables["Results"];
    gridResults.KeyFieldName = "Sample_Name";
    gridResults.DataBind();
    gridResults.SettingsPager.PageSize = 100;
 }
```

Comment: Do you working with Checkbox events?is your check box has runat='server' attribute?

Comment: Yes, al my elements have that. Is that good or bad?

Comment: you are using server side controls.could you post your source code?

Comment: You have tagged this as `asp-classic` but say that your elements have the `runat="server"` attribute?

Comment: Please edit your question and put source code there

Comment: I added the serverside code to the question above. The `runat` sits there by default. My point is that I would like to show/hide the table with clientside code from a checkbox event.

Comment: Please send the code to visible/invisible your grid

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this on the client side (e.g. in the browsers), if your table is not on the page, then you wont be able to do anything with it.

I would suggest that if you don't want to display the table on the page, then you set it's `display` style property to `none`;

C#:

```
gridResults.CssClass = "hidden";
```

CSS

```
.hidden{ display: none; }
```

Then when you change the status of the checkbox, you just toggle the `hidden` class.

JavaScript

```
document.getElementById('[gridResults_ID]').className = ""; // show the table
```

OR

```
document.getElementById('[gridResults_ID]').className = "hidden"; // hide the table again
```

Comment: I read about the CSS method and you helped me use it with a C# method of CSS. However, I get a runtime error about the `object is null or undefined`, probably meaning that the name that DevExpress uses for a control is not the same name `document.getElementById` sees. I will ask further on the DevExpress forum about this detail.

Comment: Yeah the ID which is generated within asp.net WebForms is usually changed at Runtime, so if your control ID is `gridResults` then it might be changed to something like `MyContentPlaceholder_gridResults`

Comment: DevExpress makes many things simpler, but here it looks like I am mixing highlevel programming with machine code. In fact, the string `gridResults` is mangled to something unrelated, because at the exception breakpoint, showing actual running code, I could not find another instance of that string.

Comment: @Roland Sorry I can't help you with DevExpress quirks, never used it.

Comment: I will ask further on the DevExpress.com forum. Asking a good question is important and your info helps greatly.